# How can I request a free copy of my credit report from Experian Canada?

Tags: canada, credit-report, experian

In Canada we can request a credit report for free through the mail.  I had no trouble finding TransUnion's or Equifax's request forms on their website, but Experian is another story.  [Their Canadian website](http://www.experian.ca/intl/canada.html) appears to be broken and everything else is super sketchy, pointing to their paid services.  Where can I get the form needed to request my credit report from Experian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You no longer can. Experian ceased its Canadian operations in 2009. At the time, Experian Canada had the following posted on their website:

> Effective April 17, 2009, Experian will unfortunately discontinue its Canadian consumer credit bureau operations as a result of the very difficult economic environment in Canada and around the world, which Experian believes will persist for some time. This means that as of April 18, 2009, Experian will no longer be providing credit reports out of its Canadian database regarding any consumer in Canada.
>
> We will continue to respond to ongoing consumer requests for copies of credit reports, as well as handle disputed items and other consumer assistance until April 17. After that date and upon completion of any disputes in process, all consumer information will be deleted from our database and will no longer be available to consumers or creditors.
>
> If you have not previously obtained your credit report from us or initiated a dispute on your Experian credit report, you may wish to contact one of the other credit bureaus for assistance.

This message is no longer on their website, but [a number of sites](http://www.google.ca/search?gcx=w&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Experian+will+unfortunately+discontinue+its+Canadian+consumer+credit+bureau%22) still have the message available for viewing.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info.  "very difficult economic environment in Canada" ... that's hilarious.